# Making an Old iOS App compatible to iPhone 5 creating issues

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, iphone-5

I have an iPhone App which is around two years old.
Now i tried making this App compatible with iPhone 5 but its creating one issue. I am not able to detect touches or tap on the extra lower portion added for iphone 5. I am not creating views programmatically. I am using the interface builder only. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: We are going to need more detail than that.

Comment: Ok . Please explain what detail you need ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Comment: @borrrden  - I just added this line in  applicationDidFinishLaunching: method, it should solve your problem:

window.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];  Its working fine now ....  Thanks anyways .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this line of code in your `applicationDidFinishLanuching:` method:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];    
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```