# Views on iphone 5 ios7 not scales

Tags: ios6, ios7

I have a problem - all my new project, created with the xcode 5 have such a bug: on the emulator of iphone 5, running ios7, view is always displayed like this:
[image]

But the same app looks on iphone 5 ios6 like this:

[image]

I've changed nothing in the properties, it's just an empty project with an empty view controller. So what can I do to fix this??? Maybe someone has faced such a problem?? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Default splash screen with iPhone 5 resolution. Name it Default-568h@2x.png. You might want to visit an old stackoverflow post [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution).