# auto layout in Xcode 5 ios 7. How to create app that works in both iphone 4 and iphone 5

Tags: ios, autolayout

I own an iphone 4 device and do not have immediate access to iphone 5. I am using the simulator to test things out. I have already tested my app on iphone 4 and its simulator and it looks fine. When I run the app on iphone 5 screens (4-inch screen simulator), the app does not seem to work and I get two black empty spaces on top and bottom (see below):

[image]

I suspect there is more to making an app for both iphone 4 and iphone 5 than switching autolayout on (which is the case for me.) I am going to read up on autolayout more now but thought I would throw this in here to confirm if I am not missing something obvious.

Thanks!

UPDATE: 
To solve this issue, you need to generate a launch image of size 640X1136. The question is how do you do that since in the simulator you would need this image for it to work properly?  The solution is to generate *ANY* picture of dimension and make it the Default@2x image. LAunch simulator - the app would look normal now. Now you can go ahead and generate a "REAL"  launch image of this size and replace the dummy one!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Comment: possible. I looked at that question. I dont get the second step "Set a 4-inch launch image for your app. This is how you get 1136 px screen height (without it, you will get 960 px with black margins on top and bottom)." How do you "set a 4-inch launch image" for your app? Also, looks like the only way for me to know if there is an issue with screen resolutions in iphone 5 is to get hold of a device. I realize, eventually I will have to, but was hoping that I can verify things with simulators.

Comment: OK The stackoverflow link and the article at http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/12/31/retina-4-support.html tell me that I need to generate a correct launch image.

Comment: Solved - added the solution in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you need to generate a launch image of size 640X1136. The question is how do you do that since in the simulator you would need this image for it to work properly? It is a chicken and egg problem. The solution is to generate ANY picture of dimension and make it the Default@2x image. LAunch simulator - the app would look normal now. Now you can go ahead and generate a "REAL" launch image of this size and replace the dummy one!