# compatibility issue for iphone 4 and iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am developing an Application for iphone. I am using xib for design screens. How can i make this application for iPhone 5 and iphone 4s. Please help me on that reply with example.

Thanks

Comment: whts the Ipad tag doing here???your question doesn't seem that you have asked something related to ipad?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three method for UI adjustment for different resolution device

1)---------------------------------First method-------------------------------------------

```
-(int)setScreenOf
    {   
        if([self isPad])
        {
            //return value 
            //code for ipad
        }
        else
        {        
            CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            if (screenBounds.size.height ==568) //height can be dynamic as per device
            {
                 //return value
                // code for 4-inch screen           
            }
            else
            {    //return value
                // code for 3.5-inch screen           
            }  
        }

    }
```

2)-----------------------------------second method-------------------------

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE

you can make different xib for different device and navigate app according to that.

    if(IS_IPAD)
        { 
            startVc=[[Start alloc]initWithNibName:@"start_ipad" bundle:nil];
            //xib For ipad
        }
        else
        {
            if(isiPhone5 )
            {
                startVc=[[Start alloc]initWithNibName:@"start_iphone" bundle:nil];
                //xib for iphone5
            }
            else
            {
                startVc=[[Start alloc]initWithNibName:@"Start" bundle:nil]; 
                //xib for 3.5 inch device
            }

        }

nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:startVc];
```

3)-------------------------------------Third method-----------------

you can use single xib for different device,but it will become complex to manage if your ui contain to much images.

[image]

you can adjust your UI Control OR Re-size your Control Using this authorize property.
how your UI-Control will take effect will be shown by Example window beside it.

1. The Inner Arrow will Make your UI Control small and large as per device
   resolution
2. The outer bound will hold down your control at specific
   corner on center.

Answer (score 0):

you need two design two xib files one with 3.5 inch retina(iphone 4) and another is for 4 inch retina(iphone 5) and when you call that xib you need to check condition.

```
#define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE
#define isiPhone4  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)?TRUE:FALSE
```

define above stattement in constant.h file

and then check following condition in your view controller when you push or change viewcontroller

```
if (isiPhone5) // check wheather a phone is iphone 5 or not
{

    yourViewController *objyourViewController=[[yourViewController   alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourViewController_iphone5" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objyourViewController animated:YES];
}
else if (isiPhone4) // check wheather a phone is iphone 4 or not
{
    yourViewController *objyourViewController=[[yourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourViewController_iphone4" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objyourViewController animated:YES];
}
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Hi Maul, I have to declare this thing in class or Appdelegate method.

Comment: in class after you finished your all import statement

Comment: If you are adding the AppDelegate.h in your controller this would still work

Comment: the above statement with define that you have to include in constant.h file which u have to create so you can use that in your all class and below condition is you have to check where you perform push opeartion either on button click etc.

Comment: just declare it into .pch file you can use it over the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Check In Xib ..[image]

Only Upper and left Part enable ..then try it..