# How to handle graphics in iPhone 4,4s and iPhone 5,5c,5s

Tags: iphone, retina-display, iphone-5

So early when working with iPhone Retina and non-Retina, I used to handled images as "image.png" and "image@2X.png", and that used to do the trick in handling graphics.

But what I am facing now is that I am no more building for iPhone 3,3g,3gs. That means all images are  for retina now, so the question is that how to handle iPhone 5,5c,5s images. As these devices  vertical resolution is more than 960 pixels.

Do I need to make two separate image sets for iPhone 4,4s and iPhone 5,5c,5s?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 1):

no, you need not to make two separate image sets for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 series, it's only issue if you want to have whole screen image for some backgrounds for example... different images only for start screens.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

icons and non-full screen graphics are probably the same on iPhone 4 & 5. For full screen wallpapers you need separate sets for different resolutions based on device here are the naming conventions you can use

```
image.png -> iPhone (non-retina)
image@2x.png -> iPhone 4s/4 (retina)
image-568h@2x.png -> iPhone 5
image~ipad.png -> iPad (non-retina)
image@2x~ipad.png -> iPad (retina)
```

refer this [apple design guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) and http://www.iosres.com

Comment: No. This is definitely not true. The iPhone4 and iPhone5 screens have the same per-area-resolution. The only difference is the SIZE (size != resolution). The 568h modifier only applies to the LAUNCH image, which has a different size.

Comment: icons and non-full screen graphics are probably the same on iPhone 4 & 5.  However, if you have full-screen background images, or full-width / height background images for toolbars etc you will have problems. Your 480-high images will most likely get stretched (and will probably look horrid as a result).

Comment: That's true :) But It doesn't sound like that was meant by the OQ. Sou should edit the answer to point that out :-)