# How can I make my app's view compatible with 3.5 inch display in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, ios7, view, ios6, screen

I've been working on an app that was for 4 inch screens but I found out that I have to make it compatible with 3.5 inch displays too, i searched for solutions but they didnt work for me i still get the clipped part at the bottom

sorry if my question is stupid im still new to Xcode environment and programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

1. Autolayout has to be enabled in your views (even cells)
2. You have to make your images (backgrounds) 1136x640 (HxW) too

This information has been answered many times before, you can read more specific info: [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

I used 4 inch screen's condition for the same problem. first define this as

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 568 )
```

Then i used this condition to set frames of IBOutlet for 4inch screen and 3.5 inch screen as

```
    if(IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        //set frames as per 4 inch screens
    }
    else
    {
        //set frames as per 3.5 inch screens
    }
```

This will help you to design for different size screens of iphone.