# Upgrade old iOS Application to support multiple screen size

Tags: ios, iphone

Our iOS application was written in 2009 when there was no story board.

All the positioning has been done by hard coding in the application.

This was done for 3.5 inch screen. Though it didn't look good but worked in iPhone5 also which is 4 inch and better resolution.

The application has a lot of business logic so I do not find a easy way to upgrade it to story board. I want to upgrade the application so that it works fine in all the iPhone screen sizes without any problem. I want to remove hard coded absolute value values with relative values,  so that it can support iPhone 6 also without much modifications, when it arrives.

How should I upgrade the application? How to replace absolute values by relative?

Note: I am not concerned about supporting my app for iPad.

Comment: I think you gave yourself your answers: You specified you want to replace absolute values by relative, this is the good way... I am not sure to understand your meaning by "`how` to replace absolute values with relative values", you will have in most of case to base your values on `self.view.frame.size.width` and `self.view.frame.size.height`.

Comment: I think you should write your UI from scratch. A lot has changed since 2009, design guidelines, paradigms, API, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)