# image suffixes for all iDevices for retina displays

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, ios8

When it comes to optimizing graphics on iDevices there has been suffixes added ever since the iPhone 4S with the @2x then there was the 5 with @2x_568h or something like that. What are the extensions for all of the active iDevices on iOS 7 and 8

iPhone 4:

iPhone 4S:

iPhone 5:

iPhone 5C:

iPhone 5S:

iPhone 6:

iPhone 6+:

iPad 2:

iPad 3:

iPad 4:

iPad Mini:

iPad Mini 2:

iPad Mini 3:

iPad Air:

iPad Air 2:

There are just so many iDevices now, i wanted a complete list so it would be easier to look at.

Comment: [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) may help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a simple chart, let me know if its wrong

[image]

The rest of the info can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) thanks to : [Joachim Isaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson)

Comment: the image for iPhone 4 is the same with iPhone 4S

Comment: @TonyMkenu but isn't the iPhone 4s retina and the 4 not retina?