# How to identify iphone (3g,4s,5) version programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find iPhone/iPod Device model(3G,3GS,4,4S) by code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426518/how-to-find-iphone-ipod-device-model3g-3gs-4-4s-by-code)
>   [Detect device type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139430/objective-c-how-detect-iphone-iphone5-and-ipad)

I want to identify iphone's model (3g,4s,5) programmatically.

then How can I find it?

Comment: This link might help..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426518/how-to-find-iphone-ipod-device-model3g-3gs-4-4s-by-code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can easily detect iphone 3gs-4s, iphone5 and iPad with below condition:-

```
 if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
 {
     if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
     {

          //iphone 5
     }
     else
     {
         //iphone 3.5 inch screen iphone 3g,4s 
     }
 }
 else
 {
        //[ipad]
 }
```

just visit my answer at this 
[Detect device type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139430/objective-c-how-detect-iphone-iphone5-and-ipad/13139561#13139561)

Comment: I think that this answer should be updated since we have iPhone 6 and 6+.

Answer (score 6):

Please use the following code

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>

NSString* machineName()
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Identify your device type using following code

```
if([machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])
{
    deviceType = @"iPhone 3G";
}
else if([machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])
{
    deviceType = @"iPhone 3GS";
}
else if([machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"] || [machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"] || [machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])
{
    deviceType = @"iPhone 4";
}
else if([machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])
{
    deviceType = @"iPhone 4S";
}
else if([machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])
{
    deviceType = @"iPhone 5";
}
else if([machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])
{
    deviceType = @"iPod Touch 1G";
}
else if([machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"] || [machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPod2,2"])
{
    deviceType = @"iPod Touch 2G";
}
else if([machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])
{
    deviceType = @"iPod Touch 3G";
}
else if([machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])
{
    deviceType = @"iPod Touch 4G";
}
else if([machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])
{
    deviceType = @"iPod Touch 5G";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the UIDevice (Hardware) category by [Erica Sadun](http://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/)

It can be used as:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformType]   // ex: UIDevice4GiPhone

[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString] // ex: @"iPhone 4G"
```

Comment: have you tried this code?

Comment: when I use this code its give me warning "instance method +platformString not found"

Comment: You would need to Import the category .h file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code for this:

```
NSString *device()
{
    struct utsname devInfo;
    uname(&devInfo);

    return [NSString stringWithCString:devInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Make sure that you import  `#import <sys/utsname.h>`

Answer (score 1):

HI please use below code

```
[UIDevice currentDevice] platformType]   // returns UIDevice4GiPhone
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString] // returns @"iPhone 4G"
```

or please check ratina

```
+ (BOOL) isRetina
{
    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        return [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0 ? YES : NO;

    return NO;
}
```

or check ios version

```
   + (BOOL) isIOS5
    {
        NSString *os5 = @"5.0";
        NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

        //    currSysVer = @"5.0.1";
        if ([currSysVer compare:os5 options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending) //lower than 4
        {
            return NO;
        }
        else if ([currSysVer compare:os5 options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending) //5.0.1 and above
        {        
            return YES;
        }
        else // IOS 5
        {
            return YES;
        }

        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: there is no `platformString` or `platformType` method for `UIDevice `class.

Answer (score 0):

You can get these using [uidevice-extension](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension)
What you need are the following funcitons:

```
- (NSString *) platform;
- (NSString *) hwmodel;
- (NSUInteger) platformType;
- (NSString *) platformString;
```

from UIDevice-Hardware.h