# Is it possible to get the specific iPhone model number?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)
>   [How to find iPhone/iPod Device model(3G,3GS,4,4S) by code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426518/how-to-find-iphone-ipod-device-model3g-3gs-4-4s-by-code)

I know there is a way to get the model and localized model of the phone by using the command [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]  or [[UIDevice currentDevice] localizedModel], but on several iPhones, both commands generate the same result, which is "iPhone" (or "iPad" for all iPads).

I was hoping to find a way to detect whether the device is an iPhone 3, 3S, 4, 4S, or 5 (or iPad 1, 2, etc).  Is this value hidden within the uniqueIdentifier, or is there an easier way to find this?

Comment: Discussed on:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk

Comment: Duplicate of [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk) and [Detect the specific iPhone/iPod touch model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model)

Comment: And as noted in the answers to those duplicate questions, you shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this iphonedevsdk post](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/21423-get-the-type-of-the-iphone-programmatically.html),

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>

struct utsname u;
uname(&u);

NSString *nameString =  [NSString stringWithCString:u.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Check [this blog "iPhone @2x Graphics, scale, and iPad"](http://www.markj.net/iphone-4-2x-graphics-scale-ipad/) and [this list of identifiers](http://www.everyi.com/by-identifier/ipod-iphone-ipad-specs-by-model-identifier.html) as well.