# Are there any APIs to tell iPhones apart?

Tags: iphone, c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)

I am writing a app in C and I am wondering if there is any way to have the application tell the  different generations of `iPhones` apart. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have used:

```
#import "UIDevice+machine.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

...

sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
```

Although I have heard it is deprecated in iOS 5.

Comment: Any that work with iOS5?