# Objective-C Getting the device version

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-ios)
>   [How to check iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version)

I am using this function to get the device name

```
NSString *device=[UIDevice currentDevice].model;
```

it returns me, for example, "iPhone" .

is there a way to get the device version, for example, "iPhone 4S".

Comment: Oh, I linked to the wrong duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>

- (NSString *)deviceModel
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: this functon returns me "iPhone 4.1" and not "iPhone 4S" any reason ?

Comment: iPhone 4.1 = iPhone 4S, iPhone 3.1 = iPhone 4, iPhone 2.1 = iPhone 3GS, iPhone 1.2 = iPhone 3G and iPhone 1.1 = iPhone 1G.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString]
```

That will normally return if it is iPhone 4S...

Comment: That's not a part of the standard UIDevice API: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html