# Check iPod Touch hardware performance programatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipod-touch

I stuck with a weird problem . I am having two iPod touch devices for testing purpose both are having same platform i.e. iPod touch 4G but different performance in terms of speed.
To check device platform i have used following link : [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)

My app is working perfectly for both the iPod touch but for one iPod touch it is crashing because of device performance issue.  I want to distinguish between iPod Touch device of same platform but different performance so that I can make changes to my app as per device performance.

Is there any way to check iPod Touch device 
hardware performance programatically.

Thanking you in advance..