# How do you programmatically detect your iPad's generation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, camera, detection

I'm working on a program that needs to be able to detect whether or not camera hardware is present in the iPad. I assumed that the easiest way to do this was to determine what generation the device was, but if there is a simpler way to detect the hardware that works too. The iPads that this application is being designed for will likely be recently purchased and running on a standard updated version of iOS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk

Comment: I'm not really looking for what device it is as they will all be iPads of some sort. I'm really just interested in what generation of iPad it is.

Comment: Thats exactly the same answer as the question I did post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope You can simply check what device is being used!

For checking all iOS devices:

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
NSLog(deviceType);
```

In order to check for a camera

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    //there is a camera
```

Comment: Will the first choice tell me what generation the device is in addition to which device (ipod, iphone, ipad) the app is running on?