# How to know device type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to figure out a simple way of knowing what is my `Device` type.

I already know about

```
  [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

which give me the general type.

But what I really need is to now wether it is 4, 4S, 5 or any other type of `iPhone`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can get your platform and device type by using this method

```
- (NSString *) platformString{
    // Gets a string with the device model
    size_t size;  
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);  
    char *machine = malloc(size);  
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);  
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
    free(machine); 
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"iPhone 4 (CDMA)";    
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (1 Gen)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (2 Gen)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (3 Gen)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (4 Gen)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (5 Gen)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,2"])      return @"iPad 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
    return platform;
}
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks. Do you happen to know what the platform strings for iPhone6 and iPhone6+ are?

Answer (score 1):

Hi use this class for get Device types and Device Version from this bellow link..

[UIDeviceHardware](https://gist.github.com/1323251)

just read the instruction that how to use and how to get the platform...

Here you got response like for Example... Verizon iPhone 4,iPhone 4S,iPod Touch 1G,iPod Touch 2G,etc..

i hope this helpful to you...

Comment: Would have been simpler with a line of code but that will do :) I noticed that the iPhone 5 is not there. Do you know its code?

Comment: hey i think for this we must use latest code for that wait i will post code if i success for that..

Comment: @user1461635 hey just try with log dude.. like NSString *platform = [self platform]; NSLog(@"\n\n PlatForm ==>> %@",platform);

Comment: @user1461635 in that case for iphone just use.. if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5";

Answer (score 1):

I updated the list with the currently available devices. I suggest to make a category on `UIDevice`, let's call it `UIDevice+Platform`, and add the following two methods:

```
- (NSString *)rawPlatform
{
    static NSString *platform = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        size_t size;
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
        char *machine = malloc(size);
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
        platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
        free(machine);
    });
    return platform;
}

- (NSString *)exactModel
{
    static NSString *platform = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        platform = [self rawPlatform];
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])
            platform = @"iPhone 1G";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])
            platform = @"iPhone 3G";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])
            platform = @"iPhone 3GS";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])
            platform = @"iPhone 4";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])
            platform = @"Verizon iPhone 4";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])
            platform = @"iPhone 4S";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])
            platform = @"iPhone 5";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])
            platform = @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])
            platform = @"iPhone 5C";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])
            platform = @"iPhone 5C (GSM+CDMA)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])
            platform = @"iPhone 5S";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])
            platform = @"iPhone 5S (GSM+CDMA)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])
            platform = @"iPhone 6+";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])
            platform = @"iPhone 6";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])
            platform = @"iPod Touch 1G";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])
            platform = @"iPod Touch 2G";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])
            platform = @"iPod Touch 3G";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])
            platform = @"iPod Touch 4G";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])
            platform = @"iPod Touch 5G";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])
            platform =  @"iPad 1";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])
            platform = @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])
            platform =  @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])
            platform = @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])
            platform = @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])
            platform =  @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])
            platform = @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])
            platform = @"iPad 2";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])
            platform = @"iPad Mini (Wifi)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])
            platform = @"iPad Mini";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])
            platform = @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])
            platform = @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])
            platform = @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])
            platform = @"iPad 3 (4G,3)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])
            platform = @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])
            platform = @"iPad 4 (4G,2)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])
            platform = @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])
            platform = @"iPad Air (Wifi)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])
            platform = @"iPad Air (GSM+CDMA)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,3"])
            platform = @"iPad Air";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])
            platform = @"iPad Mini 2 (GSM)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])
            platform = @"iPad Mini 2 (CDMA)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,6"])
            platform = @"iPad Mini 2 (Wifi)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])
            platform = @"iPad Mini 3 (Wifi)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])
            platform = @"iPad Mini 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])
            platform = @"iPad Mini 3";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])
            platform = @"iPad Air 2 (Wifi)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])
            platform = @"iPad Air 2 (GSM+CDMA)";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])
            platform = @"Simulator";
        else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])
            platform = @"Simulator";
    });

    return platform;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `UIDevice` Class a property to find out type of iPhone:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) NSString    *systemVersion;     // e.g. @"4.0"
```

Comment: He doesn't want to know the OS version but what device the user is using.