# Allowing univeral iOS build to run on iPad1 but not iPod touch 3G

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod-touch, info.plist

As far as I can tell, there aren't any "performance" criteria that you can specify to exclude specific iOS devices via info.plist.

Is it possible, via info.plist, to allow a universal app to run on iPad1, but not on iPhone 3GS/3G? Right now I use the gyroscope requirement (which my app does make use of), as a crutch to support only iPhone 4+ and iPad 2+.

To be absolutely clear, I want to make the app AVAILABLE FOR DOWNLOAD in the App Store on iPad1, but not on iPhone 3GS. This question is not about runtime query of the device from code.

Is my best/only option to create multiple binaries, and remove the gyroscope build from the iPad build (typically called the "HD" build) but leave it there for iPhone/iPod touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer seems to be "no".

On the up-side, iPad1 only has 256Mb memory, so you need to make your app fit in 256Mb anyway, so it should work on the 3GS. The difference in CPU speed is significant though.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question:
[Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)

It goes over determination of different iOS devices. So, you can explicitly support (or not support) some specific model.

Comment: This is ruintime only. It doesn't prevent display of the app in the app store on devices that I don't support, and as a paid app that would be catastrophic.

Comment: @Alex: I would recommend to edit your question and add this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Requiring armv7 will drop out everything <3gs, but still includes ipad1. That's the closest I see.