# Conditionals for iPhone models. E.g. if > iPhone 4, if > iPhone 3GS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

How can I make a conditional cases based on the **model of the iPhone** (not of iOS version) like so?

```
int myResolution = 10;

if ( model >= iPhone3GS ) {
    myResolution = 100;
}

if ( model >= iPhone4 ) {
    myResolution = 120;
}

if ( model >= iPhone5 ) {
    myResolution = 200;
}
```

Basically so I can quickly set the resolution for some custom OpenGL drawing to manually tweak the performance.

Comment: Read the screen size.

Comment: @dasdom 3G and 3GS have the same screen size. So does the iPhone 6 (well, maybe)

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk

Comment: @jamapag thanks, but it doesn't really allow for `model >= iPhone5` to be future proof. I though this would be quite a common task...

Comment: Have a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version

Comment: You are taking the wrong approach. It sounds like you wish to adjust the resolution based on the performance of the device. Instead of hardcoding `myResolution` based on the device model, do a quick timing test at the start of the app. See how long it takes to perform a fixed calculation or iterate through a loop. Calculate an appropriate resolution based on the result. This way your app adapts to any device.

Comment: @maddy I agree. However, this is a bit of a quickie whilst polishing up a project.

Answer (score 1):

Check the comments here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8107

They implement a DeviceDetection class to perform this task using this approach:

```
NSString *model= [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
struct utsname u;
uname(&u);
NSLog(@"%@",u.machine);
```