# Windows Phone: Determine Device (Make, Model etc)

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there a way to determine the Device details in Windows Phone?

[Example Answer for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)

I'm using **DeviceStatus** class but it gives a cryptic Device name and Version.

```
DeviceStatus.DeviceManufacturer: "NOKIA"
DeviceStatus.DeviceName: "RM-821_eu_denmark_251"
Environment.OSVersion: "Microsoft Windows NT 8.0.10211.0"
```

Is there a better way to get the device details in user friendly way?

*What I need:*

```
DeviceStatus.DeviceManufacturer: "NOKIA"
DeviceStatus.DeviceName: "Nokia 920"
Environment.OSVersion: "Microsoft Windows Phone 8"
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no official way to do this but [Alan Mendelevich](http://devblog.ailon.org/devblog/) has created an open source (MIT Licenese) solution to resolving the device names.
Find it at 
https://github.com/ailon/PhoneNameResolver

It doesn't do the OS version, but as there are fewer of them you could do this yourself.
All the released versions are published by Microsoft at:

[Windows Phone 7 update history](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/basics/update-history)
  [Windows Phone 8 update history](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/windows-phone-8-update-history)

Comment: Hi just a small question in addition to this, is it possible for clients to change the device name ? and thanks for the solution !

Answer (score 1):

Very Useful Link:[how to get the devicename and the manufacturername of the windows phone device using c](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/05/how-to-get-the-devicename-and-the-manufacturername-of-the-windows-phone-device-using-c/)

```
 object  manufacturerObject;
            Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceManufacturer", out manufacturerObject);
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DEvice Model NO. {0}", manufacturerObject.ToString());
```