# How can I detect if an iOS device supports the blur effect?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios7

It appears that different iOS devices render `UINavigationBar`s with `barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack` and `translucent = YES` very differently. Consider:

iPhone 4, no tint:
[image: iPhone 4, no tint]

iPhone 5, no tint:
[image: iPhone 5, no tint]

iPhone 4, `barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.5f]`:
[image: iPhone 4, tinted]

iPhone 5, `barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.5f]`:
[image: iPhone 5, tinted]

The iPhone 5 produces the desired effect without a tint, but the 4 is opaque. Adding a semitransparent tint makes the 4 look good, but screws up the 5.

The same holds true for the iPad 2 and 3, and theoretically any device that does not support the iOS 7 blur effects.

Short of blacklisting these older devices, how can I detect if a device supports the blurring so that I can conditionally work around the rendering differences? Or is there a way to normalize the appearance without using a tint at all?

Comment: There is no public API for that despite it being requested constantly by developers since beta seed 1. Checking for device model is not a solution because users can turn it off on newer devices.

Comment: @FilipRadelic Whoa, really? How can I disable the effect on a newer device?

Comment: Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Increase Contrast

Answer (score 1):

What about this UIDevice category along with observing for UIAccessibilityReduceTransparencyStatusDidChangeNotification?

```
@interface UIDevice (Additions)

@property (readonly) NSString *platform;
@property (readonly) BOOL canBlur;

@end


@implementation UIDevice (Additions)

- (NSString *)platform {
    int mib[] = { CTL_HW, HW_MACHINE };
    size_t len = 0;
    sysctl(mib, 2, NULL, &len, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(len);
    sysctl(mib, 2, machine, &len, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    free(machine);

    return platform;
}

- (BOOL)canBlur {
    if(NSStringFromClass([UIVisualEffectView class]) && UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion.floatValue >= 8.0 && !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()) {
        NSString *platform = self.platform;
        CGFloat deviceVersion = [[[platform stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9,.]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, platform.length)] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."] floatValue];

        if([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"]) {
            return YES;
        } else if([platform rangeOfString:@"iPhone"].location != NSNotFound) {
            return (deviceVersion >= 4.1);
        } else if([platform rangeOfString:@"iPod"].location != NSNotFound) {
            return (deviceVersion >= 5.1);
        } else if([platform rangeOfString:@"iPad"].location != NSNotFound) {
            return (deviceVersion >= 3.4);
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Don't forget to #include  in your implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is what you want to do. Just to write conditional code for different devices:

[Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Like I said in the question, that is a workaround that works most of the time, but it's not a real solution.