# iOS 7 translucent navigation bar sometimes

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

When I write an app an view it on my phone, I have a non-translucent navigation bar. However, when I view on an iPod touch, it does have a translucent bar. This seems to vary from device to device, and it's not app specific either.

This has happened with three different apps I've worked on, with all sorts of devices. All of them are using `UINavigationController` through a storyboard.

I have seen this in several of my applications now, and I'm wondering if there's a setting I'm missing. Has anyone else seen this, or know why it happens?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412094/how-can-i-detect-if-an-ios-device-supports-the-blur-effect

Comment: In short, the difference is caused by the fact that only certain devices are capable of rendering iOS 7’s blur and translucency effects. Those devices instead use flat colors or something simpler to render.