# Font type and color based on device

Tags: ios, swift, uifont, uiblureffect

I have a UI that looks good on all iOS 8 devices I've tried so far except the iPad 3 - the blur effect doesn't work so my white text is hard to read. Is there a way I can change the color of that font just for that one device? (are there other iOS 8 compatible devices that don't have the blur effect?) Is this the best way to handle it?

thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's done by defining behavior for each specific device. You can find out the device type in runtime:

https://gist.github.com/Jaybles/1323251

Example code:

```
UIDeviceHardware *h=[[UIDeviceHardware alloc] init];
if ( [h platformString] isEqualToString:@"iPhone4"] )
{
        // don't use blur
}
```

As for which devices support blur, you can use code from here:

[How can I detect if an iOS device supports the blur effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412094/how-can-i-detect-if-an-ios-device-supports-the-blur-effect)