# How to get only iPhone 6 Plus to launch in landscape?

Tags: xcode, orientation, iphone-6-plus

I have an app that works very well on the iPhone in portrait only and iPad in landscape only. Based on the screen size of the iPhone 6 Plus, I'd like to get it to work in landscape only as well.

Currently, I have Portrait selected in Device Orientation for iPhone and Landscape only for iPad with proper launch images as well.

I could certainly go to a Launch.xib for both, but I'm not sure how to force only the iPhone 6 Plus to run in landscape.

Comment: I believe this might be a step in the right direction for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584208/identify-new-iphone-model-on-xcode-5-5c-5s

Comment: Hi @pizzafilms, did you find a solution to start your app in landscape? I have the same issue but I need to force my 6 plus to start always in portrait.

Comment: Sadly, no. I can start an iPhone in Portrait only and an iPad in Landscape only, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do anything like that depending on the model of iPhone, etc..

Answer (score -3):

1. Locate your launch images in your xcassets file
2. In the utilities panel check portrait and landscape for "iOS 8 and later"
3. Add new assets for iOS 8

Comment: But there's no way to differentiate for iPhone 6 Plus. Just to be clear, I want all iPhones except 6+ in portrait only and 6+ in landscape only.