# How to get Current Device & Current platform in iOS ?

Tags: ios

I am a new developer in iOS Developing. I faced a problem on current device. According to requirement i have to design app for all device. So anybody can help me how to get Current device & current platform of iOS?

For current device i am using this code:

```
 NSString *deviceType = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
```

My requirement is i have to adjust `UITableView` row height according to device.

I think you got my question. If you need any information please tell me.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: U want current device and platform means?

Comment: Why do you need to know the device to adjust the table view size? Simply base the size off of the size of the view controller's view.

Comment: no my requirement is like this . coz in iPhone 3G its not coming proper due to status bar

Comment: ok , i got your issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584208/identify-new-iphone-model-on-xcode-5-5c-5s/19584526?noredirect=1#comment40563547_19584526 Check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok try this one.

```
NSString *deviceType = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]; // for current device

if ([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
{
    NSString *platform = [self platformRawString];
    NSLog(@"platform :%@",platform);
    // To set the half cut in the last cell.

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])
        //cellHeight = 39.5;
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])
        //cellHeight = 42;
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])
        //cellHeight = 42.5;
    else
        //cellHeight = 40.0;
}
```

Method for getting platform

```
- (NSString *)platformRawString
{
  size_t size;
  sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
  char *machine = malloc(size);
  sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
  NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
  free(machine);
  return platform;
}
```

Comment: If you need this code to size a table view you are doing it wrong.

Comment: no need of size a tableview i have to show cell height according to device

Comment: @SRNayak Sorry, my comment was meant for the OP.