# Having issue with detect iPhone 6/Plus on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to build a version of my app specifically for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus , whereas I don't have any hardware , I have to test on the simulator ! but it seems , simulator has a strange bug ! first and for most I get screen resolutions and scales , by this code :

```
    UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
NSLog(@"Screen bounds: %@, Screen resolution: %@, scale: %f, nativeScale: %f",
      NSStringFromCGRect(mainScreen.bounds), mainScreen.coordinateSpace, mainScreen.scale, mainScreen.nativeScale);
```

so here is how detect iPhone 6 and 6Plus (Portrait mode):

```
#define iPhone6 ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 667)

#define iPhone6Plus ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 736)
```

the problem is ! when I lunch my app on iPhone6/Plus simulator , compiler gives me the sceen information of iPhone 4" display :

```
    2014-09-28 12:32:08.153 WOD[2924:42290] 
Screen bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}, Screen resolution: <UIScreen: 0x7fa15be0f9b0; bounds = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x7fa15bd0d4a0; 
size = 640.000000 x 1136.000000>>, scale: 2.000000, nativeScale: 2.000000
```

But it works fine on new project ! (I cannot create a new project and start over again !).
I `cleaned code` , `delete build folder` , `change project's name` ,and reset `Simulator contents setting` but still gives me the information of 4" display ! .

I have checked this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584208/identify-new-iphone-model-on-xcode-5-5c-5s/19584526?noredirect=1#comment40563547_19584526) but answers require a real device !

Comment: you created this project in xcode 5 and opening in 6... right?

Comment: @FahimParkar Yes, I did !

Comment: Have you tried adding a Launch screen? Even the MainStoryboard is fine.

Comment: add launch screen for iphone 6... you might get proper size then...

Comment: Umm...  Lunch screen?

Comment: Thanks everybody I added `LunchImage` for HD retina both iPhone 6 and 6 plus , and `LunchScreen` (but deleted) and it works fine ! now it detects #define codes .

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The main reason I faced with this problem was I build my application with `Xcode 5` and open it with `Xcode 6`

**Solution :**

Add Launch Image for Retina HD 5.5 and 4.7 :

[image]

Now you can detect iPhone 6/Plus on simulator without having a real device :

```
#define iPhone6 ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && MAX([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width) == 667)
 #define iPhone6Plus ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && MAX([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width) == 736)
```

Comment: Brother same happened when iPhone 5 came... this was the only solution... BUT I forget that :D :)

Comment: You need to add images with the RIGHT sizes, or you must use Launch Screen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you need to detect iPhone 6/6Plus in landscape, use this.

```
 #define iPhone6 ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && MAX([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width) == 667)
 #define iPhone6Plus ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && MAX([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width) == 736)
```