# ios MFMessageComposeViewController ipod crash

Tags: ios, iphone, ipod, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Hi I am using `MFMessageComposeViewController` for messaging in an iPhone app.
As this is an iPhone app it also supports iPod. And when clicking on the message button the app crashes as messaging is not available on iPod. So is there a way to check whether the device is an iPod so that i can hide the message button so that the user may not click on message in iPod and crash.

This is the code I have used for messaging.

```
- (IBAction)Message:(id)sender
{
MFMessageComposeViewController *messaging=[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init];
messaging.messageComposeDelegate=self;
[messaging setBody:@"Will of the People""\n""http://bit.ly/1gZhZye"];

[self presentViewController:messaging animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}];
}
```

And this seems to be working fine in iPhone. I need a way to disable this button when the user is using iPod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [canSendText](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MFMessageComposeViewController/canSendText) class method for doing this:

```
- (IBAction)Message:(id)sender
{
   if ([MFMessageComposeViewController  canSendText])
   {
      MFMessageComposeViewController *messaging=[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init];
      messaging.messageComposeDelegate=self;
      [messaging setBody:@"Will of the People""\n""http://bit.ly/1gZhZye"];
      [self presentViewController:messaging animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
}
```

**Reference :**

> **canSendText**
>
> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the current device is
>   capable of sending text messages.
>   `+ (BOOL)canSendText`
>
> **Return Value**
>
> YES if the device can send text messages or NO if it cannot.
>   Discussion
>
> Always call this method before attempting to present the message
>   compose view controller. A device may be unable to send messages if it
>   does not support messaging or if it is not currently configured to
>   send messages. This method applies only to the ability to send text
>   messages via iMessage, SMS, and MMS.
>
> To be notified of changes in the availability of sending text
>   messages, register as an observer of the
>   MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChangeNotification
>   notification. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In MFMessageComposeViewController.h

Comment: you mean canSendText right ? May be you mixed [MFMessageComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/) and [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @JanakNirmal: Thanks Janak, it was a typo.

Comment: [MFMessageComposeViewController  canSendText] returns YES on my ipad,So it can't avoid this accident.

Answer (score 3):

There's a method on MFMEssageComposeViewController:

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

}

else {
    NSLog(@"Cannot send text");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
    if ([deviceType hasPrefix:@"iPod"])
    {
        //It's iPod;
        //Disable button
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First detect device by using following way and if device does not support messenger than show alert.

Form here you can get more idea about different device detection : 
[Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)

```
- (IBAction)Message:(id)sender
{
   NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

    if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPod Touch 5G"])  {

         // here your alert view to show msg 


    } else {

        if ([MFMessageComposeViewController  canSendText])
        {
          MFMessageComposeViewController *messaging=[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init];
          messaging.messageComposeDelegate=self;
         [messaging setBody:@"Will of the People""\n""http://bit.ly/1gZhZye"];
         [self presentViewController:messaging animated:YES completion:nil];
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`UIDevice`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/model) class to check the device type

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

if([deviceType hasPrefix:@"iPod"])
    // it's an iPod
```

or you can use `[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]` to check the message can be send from the device or not

Comment: @ CW0007007 can you please read the question carefully? it says he wants to disable button for iPod device. So I answered to that question. I know this is not the correct approch.

Comment: Well no, he want's to disable it for iPod because it's crashing due to iPod not being able to send text (this is his specific use case). My approach is a catch all approach for ALL devices that may not support texting. Whereas your approach is limited to iPod and will be difficult to maintain if multi device support is added later.

Comment: @PgmFreek May be you should have suggested use of canSendText like others have and still if he needs to disable button than try other solution like this.. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(IBAction)btnByEmailPressed:(id)sender
 {
     if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] == NO)
 {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"This device is not able to send mail or Email account is not configured." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alert show];
       return;
   }
   else
   {

       MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
       controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
       [controller setTitle:@"Invitation"];
       [controller setSubject:@"My Subject"];
       [controller setMessageBody:@"Your Text" isHTML:YES];
       [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
}

 - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
[self becomeFirstResponder];
NSString *strMailResult;
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Cancelled",@"");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Saved",@"");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Sent",@"");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Failed",@"");
        break;
    default:
        strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Not Sent",@"");
        break;
}
   UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"STEP-BY-STEP-STORY",@"") message:strMailResult delegate:self  cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"") otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alertView show];
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```