# How to get iOS User-Agent Strings

Tags: ios, iphone, user-agent

I'm trying to get the device's User-Agent String - the ones listed here: http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Complete_List_of_iOS_User_Agent_Strings

Here's the code I'm using:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    NSString *uaString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
```

The result I'm getting is:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X)
>   AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11D201

What I want go get is:

> Apple-iPhone4C1

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a function which can generate this string like bellow:

```
#include sys/sysctl.h
#include sys/utsname.h

size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *model =  (char*) malloc(sizeof(size_t));
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", model, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *deviceModel = [NSString stringWithCString:model encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", deviceModel);

// or

struct utsname systemInfo;
uname(&systemInfo);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Comment: This gives me back "iPhone3,1"

Comment: Yes - is there a native way to do it? Or do I need to write a method that translate it to Apple-iPhone3C2?

Comment: I didn't find any native way so far. So far what is get is you need to write a function using uname(&systemInfo);

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to access methods of `UIDevice` class. model property of UIDevice class can give you such kind of information.

Comment: [[UIDevice currentDevice] model] returns "iPhone" and nothing more (on iPhone 4)

Comment: You may try this method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk