# How do I test whether my device is an iphone 4 or an iphone 5

Tags: ios, iphone

I made a game and I have a method that I want to run differently depending whether it is an iphone 4, or 5. Does anybody know of a way to do this.

Comment: Why? What do you need to do different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
  {
   for iphone 5,5c and 5s
  }
  else
  {
  for other device 4 4s
  }
```

Comment: is there any way to test an ipod 4 or 5

Comment: you can check the height of any device using this code replace the 568 with the height of your device

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code:

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0f)
```

Comment: how would I implement ipod 4 and 5

Comment: Follow this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk/1561920#1561920

Answer (score 0):

Use [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] to get version info.

Comment: That returns the version of the OS, not the device.

Answer (score 0):

I usually add these macro definitions in the "App Name-Prefix.pch" file (so they are accessible everywhere with no need to import that file):

```
#define IS_iPHONE_5 [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height    == 568
#define IS_iPHONE   [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone
#define IS_iPAD     [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

#define iDEVICE_TYPE (IS_iPAD) ? @"iPad" : ((IS_iPHONE_5) ? @"iPhone5" : @"iPhone")
```

If I am using using .xib files, I create 3 different .xib-s for every view controller, and I put ~iPhone, ~iPhone5, and ~iPad at the end of their name. And when I need to load the corresponding nib, I just write:

```
NSString *nameOfNib = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ADWRootViewController~%@", iDEVICE_TYPE];

ADWRootViewController *rootVC = [[ADWRootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nameOfNib
                                                                        bundle:nil];
```

I hope it helped. NOTE that I do not check if it Retina or Non-Retina device in my code.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for `[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]`