# Xcode: Which device is simulator running? Comparing views across devices with FBSnapshotTestCase and Nimble-Snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fbsnapshottestcase

I am currently using FBSnapshotTestCase and Nimble-Snapshot to take snapshots of ViewControllers in my project.

I know in the Realm UI and Snapshot Testing [Video](https://news.realm.io/news/cmdu-conf-luis-ascorbe-ui-and-snapshottesting/) Luis mentioned that we can test views across devices (iPhone5 vs iPhone 6+ etc).

I want to know which device I am running on within simulator, but when I print out the model name using this extension found at this post [iOS: How to determine the current iPhone/device model in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model-in-swift)

`let modelName = UIDevice.current.modelName`

It would just say I am running in Simulator.

I was following this Stack Overflow post [How to determine the device running in the simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044221/how-to-determine-the-device-running-in-the-simulator)
 but using FBSnapshotTestCase is not necessarily related to "functionalities available".  Has anyone ran into a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `UIDevice.current.name` will give you what you're looking for when it comes to the simulator. ([However, on a device it will instead be what the owner has named their device in the settings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620015-name)).