# Get iPhone 5s app to scale to iPhone 6 resolution in Xcode Storyboard

Tags: xcode, cocoa, uistoryboard

I want my iPhone 5s app to simply upscale for the iPhone 6. I have no Launch Images in the project, but I do have the interface builder location declared in the plist to get rid of the black bars. How can I get the app to just upscale, right now it shows white space in Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question it looks like you are using absolute frame values for positioning, by setting frame.size.{width, height} and frame.origin.{x,y}.

You have two options.

- set those values programatically. It's not recommended at all but might be easier to setup. Detect what is the screen's size with [[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] size] (check for the height property) or detect the device's version (eg [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk/1561920#1561920)).
- a less slippery road is to transform your project an start using AutoLayout. There's a learning curve but it guarantees that your project will be fitting well any screen. Start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html