# How to check on which iPhone device currently run the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, size

Is there any way to check the iPhone device in Swift app. But without checking the screen size, because I try it and didn't work good.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift

Comment: @Nik. hi can you please accept anyone answer which helps you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
{
}
```

[Prefer link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk/1561920#1561920)

Comment: Yes ... please see above link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using below methods

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformType] 
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Usage example: if ur running the app in simulator
//    let deviceType : DeviceTypes = UIDevice().deviceType  
//    let deviceName : String = deviceType.rawValue

public enum DeviceTypes : String {
    case simulator      = "Simulator",
         iPad2          = "iPad 2",
         iPad3          = "iPad 3",
         iPhone4        = "iPhone 4",
         iPhone4S       = "iPhone 4S",
         iPhone5        = "iPhone 5",
         iPhone5S       = "iPhone 5S",
         iPhone5c       = "iPhone 5c",
         iPad4          = "iPad 4",
         iPadMini1      = "iPad Mini 1",
         iPadMini2      = "iPad Mini 2",
         iPadAir1       = "iPad Air 1",
         iPadAir2       = "iPad Air 2",
         iPhone6        = "iPhone 6",
         iPhone6plus    = "iPhone 6 Plus",
         unrecognized   = "?unrecognized?"
}

public extension UIDevice {
    public var deviceType: DeviceTypes {
        var sysinfo : [CChar] = Array(count: sizeof(utsname), repeatedValue: 0)
        let modelCode = sysinfo.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {
            (inout ptr: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<CChar>) -> DeviceTypes in
                uname(UnsafeMutablePointer<utsname>(ptr.baseAddress))
                // skip 1st 4 256 byte sysinfo result fields to get "machine" field
                let machinePtr = advance(ptr.baseAddress, Int(_SYS_NAMELEN * 4))
            var modelMap : [ String : DeviceTypes ] = [
                "i386"      : .simulator,
                "x86_64"    : .simulator,
                "iPad2,1"   : .iPad2,          //
                "iPad3,1"   : .iPad3,          // (3rd Generation)
                "iPhone3,1" : .iPhone4,        //
                "iPhone3,2" : .iPhone4,        //
                "iPhone4,1" : .iPhone4S,       //
                "iPhone5,1" : .iPhone5,        // (model A1428, AT&T/Canada)
                "iPhone5,2" : .iPhone5,        // (model A1429, everything else)
                "iPad3,4"   : .iPad4,          // (4th Generation)
                "iPad2,5"   : .iPadMini1,      // (Original)
                "iPhone5,3" : .iPhone5c,       // (model A1456, A1532 | GSM)
                "iPhone5,4" : .iPhone5c,       // (model A1507, A1516, A1526 (China), A1529 | Global)
                "iPhone6,1" : .iPhone5S,       // (model A1433, A1533 | GSM)
                "iPhone6,2" : .iPhone5S,       // (model A1457, A1518, A1528 (China), A1530 | Global)
                "iPad4,1"   : .iPadAir1,       // 5th Generation iPad (iPad Air) - Wifi
                "iPad4,2"   : .iPadAir2,       // 5th Generation iPad (iPad Air) - Cellular
                "iPad4,4"   : .iPadMini2,      // (2nd Generation iPad Mini - Wifi)
                "iPad4,5"   : .iPadMini2,      // (2nd Generation iPad Mini - Cellular)
                "iPhone7,1" : .iPhone6plus,    // All iPhone 6 Plus's
                "iPhone7,2" : .iPhone6         // All iPhone 6's
            ]
            if let model = modelMap[String.fromCString(machinePtr)!] {
                return model
            }
            return DeviceTypes.unrecognized
        }
        return modelCode
    }
}
```

for more detail you can refer this link [the link that i have copied this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift)
enjoy coding :)

Comment: Please state where you get code from. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel Up voted your comment. From next time itself i wont forget to add the link Thank you :)