# IOS - How to determine device(iphone6 ,iphone5, iphone4) in my C++ code?

Tags: c++, ios

I try to write c++ framework for ios app, and want distinguish iphone6 and iphone4, which have different cpu performance. I should close some modules only for iphone4. So is there a way to achieve it? Thanks.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk) only about object-c solution, But I want ask if there is  any api for c codes.

Comment: Since you can call Objective-C methods from C or C++ code, it's hard to think of a reason why the Objective-C solution wouldn't be viable in the situation you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The following could be used to get a C string representing the model of an iOS device

```
size_t size;  
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);  
char *machine = malloc(size);  
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
```

This solution is taken from [this Objective-C based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13679404/1702077), which also includes a list of what will be stored in `machine`. A list of these values can also be found on [The iPhone Wiki](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models).

The value for the iPhone 4 is `iPhone3,x`, with `x` being either 1, 2, or 3, depending on the specific model. The value for the iPhone 6 is `iPhone7,x`, with `x` being either 1 or 2.