# How can I programmatically check which device my app is running on? (Swift and Sprite Kit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to create if statements testing for which device the app is running on. For example, if the app is running on an iPhone 5s, change node positioning. Does anyone know how to create these statements? Thanks.

I want to test for the screen size.

EDIT:

I've found the answer. I download the SDK from here using Cocopods. Once instilled, I implemented the following code, so I could test for the size of the screen. I can then add where I want to nodes to be positioned in the if statements. It's a bit of a pain, but it's the best solution I could come up with.

```
let device = Device()

let iPhone4sSizedGroup: [Device] =
[.iPhone4, .iPhone4s, .Simulator(.iPhone4), .Simulator(.iPhone4s)]

if device.isOneOf(iPhone4sSizedGroup) {


}

let iPhone5sSizedGroup: [Device] =
    [.iPodTouch5, .iPodTouch6, .iPhone5, .iPhone5s, .iPhone5c, .Simulator(.iPhone5), .Simulator(.iPhone5s), .Simulator(.iPhone5c), .Simulator(.iPodTouch5), .Simulator(.iPodTouch6)]

if device.isOneOf(iPhone5sSizedGroup) {


}

let iPhone6sSizedGroup: [Device] =
[.iPhone6, .iPhone6s, .Simulator(.iPhone6), .Simulator(.iPhone6s)]

if device.isOneOf(iPhone6sSizedGroup) {


}.
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/30665494/3004003 and other answers in that question

Comment: It's the same API, you can test `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height` and `UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone`

Comment: @AxelGuilmin ok. So could u give me an example for let's say the iPhone 5s

Comment: Depending on concrete model is a "NO-NO". It is determined to break in the future. Just use that what matters: screen size!

Comment: @AxelGuilmin The scene size it is not necessarily the same size of your view

Comment: What is the real question here, do you want the device, or do you want the height?  Reword the question so that people can correctly answer you. @Eiko, getting a concrete model is not determined to break in the future, an iPhone will always be an iPhone,  now the problem here is iPhones have different sizes, so getting the model will not work.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments from here; please refrain from extensive conversation in the comments section. Harrison, if the duplicate does not solve your problem please edit your question to clarify why it is not a duplicate. The edit will automatically trigger a community review to determine if your question should be reopened. Further, please do not add the answer within the question. Answers should only be in the answers section.

Answer (score 3):

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().model
```

is what you are looking for

Comment: I basically want to change to node positioning depending on the screen size. So I need to eat for the screen size. How do I do that?

Comment: `UIDevice.currentDevice().model` just returns 'iPhone', if you need a more precise identifier as 'iPhone 11 Pro' you should call `UIDevice.currentDevice().name`. [Here is the doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620015-name)

Answer (score 1):

```
let size = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
print("This is the size you are looking for \(size)");

if size.height == 568 {
    print("As an example, this is an iPhone 5/S/C/SE")
}
```