# How can I get the device name? ("iPhone" vs "iPad" vs "iPod" vs future)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

My iOS app displays an error message of the form:

> No plumbus is currently fleemed with this iPhone

However my app also runs on the iPad and iPod Touch - and presumably any other new iProduct apple comes out with.

I can't see any official way to get a string that returns "iPhone", "iPad" or "iPod Touch" at runtime.

I know I can use `UIUserInterfaceIdiom` but it doesn't differentiate between iPhone and iPod Touch.

Comment: See Brian Robbins answer from this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk

Comment: @Roee84 No, use the accepted answer (Adam's), not Brian's.