# I am getting one issue regarding Device Name

Tags: ios, objective-c

ONLY for iOS version 15.3.1 & 16.2, we are getting device identifiers instead of device name on screen. For Eg. 1. if im using iPhone 13, then I am getting iPhone 14,5 as a device name

1. If I am us gin iPhone 11, then I'm getting iPhone 12,1 as a device name. I want right device name, not its identifiers. What can be the solution.  It is happening only for iOS versions 15.3.1 & 16.2.

> ```
>  + (NSString *)getName:(char *)typeSpecifier
>     {
>       size_t size;
>         sysctlbyname(typeSpecifier, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
>         char *machinedetails = malloc(size);
>       sysctlbyname(typeSpecifier, answer, &size, NULL, 0);
>       NSString *results = [NSString stringWithCString:answer encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>       free(answer);
>       return results;
>     }
>     
>     + (NSString *)platform
>     {
>       return [self getName:"hw.machine"];
>     }
> ```

Thanks

please provide a solution.

Comment: How are you accessing the device name?

Comment: after writing above code, we are calling platform() method and checking for platforms. if platform Is iPhone 1,1, then return iPhone 2G as a device name and so on. @Paulw11 sir

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-ios) or [How to determine the current iPhone/device model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model)

Comment: no @HangarRash sir. I tried using [[UIDevice currentDevice] name] instead of above code, but it didn't work. its only giving problem for iOS 15.3.1 & 16.2

Comment: I'm not suggesting the use of `[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]`. The questions and answers I linked mostly make use of `sysctlbyname` and `hw.machine` to get the device code which then needs to be converted to a device type by hardcoding the list. It has always been this way.